# Attach correlation id to Guzzle 6 requests

Tags: php, symfony, microservices, guzzle

I'm wondering how to pass **correlation id** (or *request id*) to Guzzle 6 requests. I haven't found any questions which could satisfy me so I decided to create new one.

Most of my micro-services are running on *Symfony3* stack. They communicate with each other via HTTP and I use Guzzle 6 for that. I'd like to have a unique *request id* generated in entry point (where the use case - commmand or query - starts) and pass it into next requests to other services. Other app should also fetch already generated *request id* in communication with their dependent services and add it to following requests (and so on...). This request id will be helpful e.g. in logging events.

I think about the most efficient way to do this. While generating the unique id and attaching it into request metadata (e.g. in headers) in handling in Symfony is pretty easy, I don't know what to do with API clients. My thoughts so far:

- Of course, I could attach a header in every place where requests are made but it seems a bit "smelly" and hard to maintain. Moreover while creating new method in my API Client class, I need to remember to add a header to the request.
- I was also considering to create new Guzzle middleware which will be responsible for attaching a header for me. But since Symfony3 has a different implementation of `Request` than Guzzle (*PSR 7* here) I don't if it's legal :) Of course I can use Symfony's PSR Http Bridge to convert requests but I haven't used it yet and I'm afraid it can break compatibility in classes where `HttpFoundation\Request` is injected. However this solution seems to be the best so far.

I'd like to hear some advices from you. How to do it and maintain it easily keeping the principles of Clean Architecture and Clean Design?

Thanks for any answer.